# boost::filesystem::directory_iterator copy-ctor implictly deleted

Tags: c++, boost

The [`boost::filesystem::directory_iterator` reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator) (v1.48) says `directory_iterator` defines a copy constructor explicitly. I just looked at [the code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp) and it doesn't, presumably letting the compiler define the copy-ctor.

Can a situation happen where the compiler generates a move-ctor for the type, subsequently figure that the implicit copy-ctor would be ill-formed and thus delete the copy-ctor? I haven't yet reproduced it in a simple and concise code snippet, but it seems to be what's going on in my code right now with a gcc 4.7 snapshot from 2011-12-17. I don't have the issue in gcc 4.6.1 though.

Here's a taste of the error from gcc 4.7:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/interoperable.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:31,
                 from /Users/matan/Development/ouch.git/src/include/ouch/operations.hh:4,
                 from /Users/matan/Development/ouch.git/src/libouch/operations.cc:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp: In instantiation of 'const bool boost::detail::is_convertible_basic_impl<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>::value':
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:296:272:   required from 'const bool boost::detail::is_convertible_impl<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>::value'
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:419:47:   required from 'struct boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>'
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/aux_/nested_type_wknd.hpp:26:31:   required from 'struct boost::mpl::aux::nested_type_wknd<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator> >'
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/or.hpp:48:8:   required from 'struct boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>, boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >'
/usr/local/include/boost/iterator/detail/enable_if.hpp:68:12:   required from 'struct boost::iterators::enable_if<boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>, boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >, bool>'
/usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:67:12:   required from 'struct boost::detail::enable_if_interoperable<boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator, bool>'
/usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:837:323:   required by substitution of 'template<class Derived1, class V1, class TC1, class Reference1, class Difference1, class Derived2, class V2, class TC2, class Reference2, class Difference2> typename boost::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type boost::operator!=(const boost::iterator_facade<Derived1, V1, TC1, Reference1, Difference1>&, const boost::iterator_facade<Derived2, V2, TC2, Reference2, Difference2>&) [with Derived1 = boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator; V1 = boost::filesystem3::directory_entry; TC1 = boost::single_pass_traversal_tag; Reference1 = boost::filesystem3::directory_entry&; Difference1 = long int; Derived2 = boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator; V2 = boost::filesystem3::directory_entry; TC2 = boost::single_pass_traversal_tag; Reference2 = boost::filesystem3::directory_entry&; Difference2 = long int]'
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:691:49:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:137:49: error: use of deleted function 'boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(const boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&)'
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:31:0,
                 from /Users/matan/Development/ouch.git/src/libouch/operations.cc:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:581:9: note: 'boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(const boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:581:9: error: use of deleted function 'boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp>&)'
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code that makes the error occur?

Comment: I'm getting this problem with GCC 5.1 and Clang 3.8, probably because I'm using the outdated Boost 1.46.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a type can easily be movable but not copyable. For example if it has a member or a base class that is non-copyable but movable. In C++11 that could be a std::fstream.

In that case the compiler can create a move constructor for your class but will declare the copy constructor as deleted.